# Visual Code suddenly started saying 'CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles"' - Yet works in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, mingw

I'm using Visual Code to develop RP2040 projects using Picotool

Everything was working fine until yesterday when the build output started telling me it can't find MinGW

I installed everything using Shawn Hymel's how-to guides and it has been working perfectly for the past 5 months

Perhaps more frustratingly is that I can still build the programs if I open a Git Bash terminal in VS Code and use the terminal commands

Unfortunately that doesn't help me so much with debugging because I don't have any experience with command line debugging

So everything is there, installed and in PATH, but VS Code just isn't finding it

```
C:\Users\craig.h>make --version

C:\Users\craig.h>mingw32-make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for i686-w64-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Can anyone help?

Could "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set" be the crux of it?

I've tried Googling but the answers all seem to involve missing Environment Variables or missing installs

I've also tried adding CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM to User Variables ( not System Variables or PATH )

Output from using the VS Code build button:

```
[main] Building folder: RP2040_TestBed 
[main] Configuring project: RP2040_TestBed 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\VSARM\armcc\11.3 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\VSARM\armcc\11.3 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe" -SC:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed -Bc:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] PICO_SDK_PATH is C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk
[cmake] PICO platform is rp2040.
[cmake] CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "C:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\VSARM\armcc\11.3 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\VSARM\armcc\11.3 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe" -SC:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed -Bc:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build -G "MinGW Makefiles" exited with code: 1
```

Output from terminal:

```
$ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
PICO_SDK_PATH is C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk
PICO platform is rp2040.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.1
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/VSARM/armcc/11.3 rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
Build type is Debug
Using regular optimized debug build (set PICO_DEOPTIMIZED_DEBUG=1 to de-optimize)
Defaulting PICO target board to pico since not specified.
Using board configuration from C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/boards/include/boards/pico.h
-- Found Python3: C:/Users/craig.hemingway/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe (found version "3.11.0") found components: Interpreter 
TinyUSB available at C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; enabling build support for USB.
Compiling TinyUSB with CFG_TUSB_DEBUG=1
cyw43-driver available at C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/cyw43-driver
lwIP available at C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/lwip
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build
```

```
$ cd src
$ make
[  1%] Creating directories for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  2%] No download step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  3%] No update step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  4%] No patch step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  5%] Performing configure step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/VSARM/mingw/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/VSARM/mingw/mingw32/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build/elf2uf2
[  6%] Performing build step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/elf2uf2.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable elf2uf2.exe
[100%] Built target elf2uf2
[  7%] No install step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  8%] Completed 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  8%] Built target ELF2UF2Build
[ 10%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.obj
[ 11%] Linking ASM executable bs2_default.elf
[ 11%] Built target bs2_default
[ 12%] Generating bs2_default.bin
[ 13%] Generating bs2_default_padded_checksummed.S
[ 13%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[ 14%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/main.c.obj
[ 15%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/comms.c.obj
[ 16%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/dac.c.obj
[ 17%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdlib/stdlib.c.obj
[ 19%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_gpio/gpio.c.obj
[ 20%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_claim/claim.c.obj
[ 21%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_platform/platform.c.obj
[ 22%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_sync/sync.c.obj
[ 23%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_irq/irq.c.obj
[ 24%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_irq/irq_handler_chain.S.obj
[ 25%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/sem.c.obj
[ 26%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/lock_core.c.obj
[ 28%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_time/time.c.obj
[ 29%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_time/timeout_helper.c.obj
[ 30%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_timer/timer.c.obj
[ 31%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_util/datetime.c.obj
[ 32%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_util/pheap.c.obj
[ 33%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_util/queue.c.obj
[ 34%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/mutex.c.obj
[ 35%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/critical_section.c.obj
[ 37%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_uart/uart.c.obj
[ 38%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_divider/divider.S.obj
[ 39%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_runtime/runtime.c.obj
[ 40%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_clocks/clocks.c.obj
[ 41%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_pll/pll.c.obj
[ 42%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_vreg/vreg.c.obj
[ 43%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_watchdog/watchdog.c.obj
[ 44%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_xosc/xosc.c.obj
[ 46%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_printf/printf.c.obj
[ 47%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_bit_ops/bit_ops_aeabi.S.obj
[ 48%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_bootrom/bootrom.c.obj
[ 49%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_divider/divider.S.obj
[ 50%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_aeabi.S.obj
[ 51%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_init_rom.c.obj
[ 52%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_math.c.obj
[ 53%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_v1_rom_shim.S.obj
[ 55%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_int64_ops/pico_int64_ops_aeabi.S.obj
[ 56%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_aeabi.S.obj
[ 57%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_init_rom.c.obj
[ 58%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_math.c.obj
[ 59%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_v1_rom_shim.S.obj
[ 60%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_malloc/pico_malloc.c.obj
[ 61%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_mem_ops/mem_ops_aeabi.S.obj
[ 62%] Building ASM object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_standard_link/crt0.S.obj
[ 64%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_standard_link/new_delete.cpp.obj
[ 65%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_standard_link/binary_info.c.obj
[ 66%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio/stdio.c.obj
[ 67%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/reset_interface.c.obj
[ 68%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb.c.obj
[ 69%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb_descriptors.c.obj
[ 70%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040/dcd_rp2040.c.obj
[ 71%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040/rp2040_usb.c.obj
[ 73%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/device/usbd.c.obj
[ 74%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/device/usbd_control.c.obj
[ 75%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/audio/audio_device.c.obj
[ 76%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/cdc/cdc_device.c.obj
[ 77%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/dfu/dfu_device.c.obj
[ 78%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/dfu/dfu_rt_device.c.obj
[ 79%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/hid/hid_device.c.obj
[ 80%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/midi/midi_device.c.obj
[ 82%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/msc/msc_device.c.obj
[ 83%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/net/ecm_rndis_device.c.obj
[ 84%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/net/ncm_device.c.obj
[ 85%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/usbtmc/usbtmc_device.c.obj
[ 86%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/vendor/vendor_device.c.obj
[ 87%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/video/video_device.c.obj
[ 88%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/tusb.c.obj
[ 89%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/common/tusb_fifo.c.obj
[ 91%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_fix/rp2040_usb_device_enumeration/rp2040_usb_device_enumeration.c.obj
[ 92%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_unique_id/unique_id.c.obj
[ 93%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_flash/flash.c.obj
[ 94%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_adc/adc.c.obj
[ 95%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_dma/dma.c.obj
[ 96%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_i2c/i2c.c.obj
[ 97%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_pio/pio.c.obj
[ 98%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/src.dir/C_/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_spi/spi.c.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable src.elf
c:/vsarm/armcc/1142da~1.3re/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/vsarm/armcc/1142da~1.3re/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/thumb/v6-m/nofp\libg.a(libc_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
/data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-11/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/closer.c:47: warning: _close is not implemented and will always fail
c:/vsarm/armcc/1142da~1.3re/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/vsarm/armcc/1142da~1.3re/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/thumb/v6-m/nofp\libg.a(libc_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
/data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-11/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/lseekr.c:49: warning: _lseek is not implemented and will always fail
[100%] Built target src
```

But then trying the VS Code build button again after the terminal build, I get a different output:

```
[main] Building folder: RP2040_TestBed 
[main] Configuring project: RP2040_TestBed 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\VSARM\armcc\11.3 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\VSARM\armcc\11.3 rel1\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe" -SC:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed -Bc:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] PICO_SDK_PATH is C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk
[cmake] PICO platform is rp2040.
[cmake] Build type is Debug
[cmake] Using regular optimized debug build (set PICO_DEOPTIMIZED_DEBUG=1 to de-optimize)
[cmake] PICO target board is pico.
[cmake] Using board configuration from C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/src/boards/include/boards/pico.h
[cmake] TinyUSB available at C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; enabling build support for USB.
[cmake] Compiling TinyUSB with CFG_TUSB_DEBUG=1
[cmake] cyw43-driver available at C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/cyw43-driver
[cmake] lwIP available at C:/VSARM/sdk/pico/pico-sdk/lib/lwip
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: chcp
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 --
[build] [  1%] Creating directories for 'PioasmBuild'
[build] [  2%] Performing build step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[build] [  4%] Built target bs2_default
[build] [  6%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[build] [  7%] No download step for 'PioasmBuild'
[build] [100%] Built target elf2uf2
[build] [  8%] No update step for 'PioasmBuild'
[build] [  9%] No install step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[build] [ 10%] Completed 'ELF2UF2Build'
[build] [ 11%] No patch step for 'PioasmBuild'
[build] [ 12%] Performing configure step for 'PioasmBuild'
[build] [ 17%] Built target ELF2UF2Build
[build] loading initial cache file C:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/cyw43_driver/pioasm/tmp/PioasmBuild-cache-Debug.cmake
[build] CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
[build] CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
[build] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[build] See also "C:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build/pioasm/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\cyw43_driver\CMakeFiles\PioasmBuild.dir\build.make:91: pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/cyw43_driver/pioasm/src/PioasmBuild-stamp/PioasmBuild-configure] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1503: pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/cyw43_driver/CMakeFiles/PioasmBuild.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[build] [ 96%] Built target src
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/craig.hemingway/VisualCode_Workspace/RP2040_TestBed/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:02.515
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: Yeah. Same behaviour here. Suddenly stopped working. In my case a C++ project with arm-none-eabi-toolchain. Yesterday everything was fine.

Comment: 'Could "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set" be the crux of it?' - Yes, it is the immediate reason of the fault. Have you tried to specify this CMake variable with **absolute path** to `mingw32-make` utility? In VSCode CMake variables can be specified via `cmake.configureSettings` parameter in `settings.json` file (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md).

Comment: "So everything is there, installed and in PATH, but VS Code just isn't finding it" - VSCode could have **different** PATH environment variable, which doesn't contain the directory with `mingw32-make` utility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295863/vscode-terminals-path-enviroment-variable-different-from-cmd

Comment: In VS Code Git Bash terminal, 'echo %PATH%' returns '%PATH%, but in command prompt it returns the whole PATH contents. Is this the correct way to check?

Comment: In Git Bash, use `echo $PATH` instead. Also note that Git Bash uses colons to separate while cmd uses semi-colons. This is what you will get wrong trying to add an entry.

Answer (score 0):

I've added in settings.json:

```
"cmake.configureSettings": {
  "gtest_disable_pthreads": "ON",
  "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
},
```

and in cmake-kits.json I added the full path with trailing .exe as well:

```
{
    "name": "Host-gcc-arm-none-eabi",
    "compilers": {
        "C": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe",
        "CXX": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe"
    },
    "environmentVariables": {},
    "cmakeSettings": {
        "CMAKE_SIZE": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/arm-none-eabi-size.exe"
    }
}
```

Maybe it will look different with your compiler but it helped me.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to add to settings.json but where should cmake-kits.json be? Just by having the addition to settings.json gives me a new error "The system cannot find the file specified", but it doesn't tell me which file, then "CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: C:\VSARM\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile -j10 all &&". Did you ever come across these errors?

Comment: Sadly I don't know about this errors.
In my case I have a cmake-kits.json file in the .vscode folder where the different toolchains and their residence are listed.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be with the Cmake Tools Extension in VSCode. Changing it to version 1.13.45 cleared up my build errors.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/3123 They fixed the error, pre-release 1.15.2 works as well

Comment: I've checked 1.15.2 an it doesn't resolve my error.